# How does Grails async response rendering work?

Tags: grails, asynchronous, promise

I have a code snippet in a grails controller that looks like the following:

```
Future<Map<String,Object>> future1 = service.getMetrics(args1)
Future<Map<String,Object>> future2 = service.getMetrics(args2)

Map<String,Object> result1 = future1.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)
Map<String,Object> result2 = future2.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)

render([
    data1: result1,
    data2: result2
] as JSON)
```

I realized that `future1.get` and `future2.get` were blocking calls and wanted to make them asynchronous when I came upon [Grails Async Response Rendering](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/guide/async.html)

I am now considering refactoring my code to

```
task {
    Future<Map<String,Object>> future1 = service.getMetrics(args1)
    Future<Map<String,Object>> future2 = service.getMetrics(args2)

    Map<String,Object> result1 = future1.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)
    Map<String,Object> result2 = future2.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)

    render([
     data1: result1,
     data2: result2
    ] as JSON)    
}
```

This works but I want to understand how task works and how it ensures that the current thread is not blocked on the future.get and how does it render the response for the right session

Answer (score 0):

I believe Graeme clarified this even further than the current documentation in his answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126047/in-grails-3-2-4-controller-that-has-an-async-task-call-in-it-sets-request-asyn). Graeme links to the class that shows exactly how the result transformer detects and handles responses when a Promise or PromiseMap is returned.

Comment: Please, also include relevant information in this answer.

Comment: Hi Alexei, you're right, and I will.  I am actually still in the middle of troubleshooting gremlins in async handling where attributes stored in session are disappearing when calling async-handled controller actions.  I wanted to at least link a post that sheds further light (in addition to the documentation).